# Texture swapping on PSM (Playstation Mobile C#)

Tags: c#, textures, sprite, swap, playstation

I've been working on a really simple game as a base for a project in my CS course, but while mapping the movement commands, I keep having trouble making the character sprite move upwards as well as swap textures.  Whenever I try moving upwards, the character moves up one space and swaps textures, then resets to the previous position when I release the button.  I've tried a few different methods and I end up with pretty much the same result.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
public static void Update ()
    {
        // Query gamepad for current state
        var gamePadData = GamePad.GetData (0);
        pnut = pnutDefault;
        pnutDown.Position = pnut.Position;

        if ((gamePadData.Buttons & GamePadButtons.Left) != 0)
        {
            pnut.Position.X--;
        }

        if ((gamePadData.Buttons & GamePadButtons.Right) != 0)
        {
            pnut.Position.X++;
        }

        if ((gamePadData.Buttons & GamePadButtons.Down) != 0)
        {
            pnut.Position.Y++;
        }

            if ((gamePadData.Buttons & GamePadButtons.Up) != 0)
        {
            //pnutDown.Position = pnut.Position;

            pnutDown.Position.Y--;
            pnut.Position.Y--;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Where do you define pnutDefault?

Comment: The Initialize method

`pnut = new Sprite(graphics, t);
pnutDefault = pnut;`

Comment: Those might help to debug the issue you are having. Please edit your question and add the appropriate code.

Comment: @AdamZuckerman Your comment reminded me that the pnutDefault position was not being updated with the pnutDown sprite causing it to revert to the previous position each update. The new code is as follows:

Comment: `public static void Update ()
{
 var gamePadData = GamePad.GetData (0);
 pnut = pnutDefault;
 pnutDown.Position = pnut.Position;

 if ((gamePadData.Buttons & GamePadButtons.Left) != 0){
  pnut.Position.X--;
 }

 if ((gamePadData.Buttons & GamePadButtons.Right) != 0){
  pnut.Position.X++;
 }

 if ((gamePadData.Buttons & GamePadButtons.Down) != 0){
  pnut.Position.Y++;
 }if ((gamePadData.Buttons & GamePadButtons.Up) != 0){
  //pnutDown.Position = pnut.Position; 
  pnut = pnutDown; 
  pnutDown.Position.Y--;
  pnutDefault.Position = pnutDown.Position;
 }`

Comment: ok im not sure how to format that...sorry

Comment: There is an edit button just below your original question (share | edit | flag). Click there to edit your question.